# Any linear transformation is a sum of a rotation and streching. So Is it possible to decompose any $A$ real matrix into such $R$ and $S$ components?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

### The Question

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be the matrix of a linear transformation.

I have learned that any linear transformation is either a rotation, a streching, or a mirroring (with the latter one being a special type of stretching with a multiplier of $-1$).

So is it possible to algebraically decompose $A$ into a purely rotational part $R$ and a purely stretching part $S$?

### Definitions

A square matrix $R$ is a rotation matrix exactly if it is orthogonal $(R^T = R^{-1})$ and $\det(R)=1$.

An $n$ by $n$ square matrix $S$ is a stretch matrix exactly if it has $n$ real eigenvalues (counted with algebraic multiplicity). As such, $S$ has a real eigendecomposition $S = U^T \Lambda U$, where $U$ is orthogonal and $\Lambda = \text{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ with $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n \in \mathbb{R}$

### Algebraic phrasing of the Question

Given $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, does there exist $R,S \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that

1. $A = RS$
2. $R^T = R^{-1}$
3. $\det(R)=1$
4. $S = U^T \Lambda U$
5. $U^T = U^{-1}$
6. $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with real entries

Furthermore, is this decomposition unique?

Comment: *I have learned that any linear transformation is either a rotation, a stretching, or a mirroring*... which is very strange!

Comment: A stretching is when you can define a direction (an eigendirection) on which the linear transformation is equivalent to mulitplying by a number. In 3 dimensions or more, it is entirelly possible for a linear transformation to act as a rotation on a plane, while also stretching the space in a different direction.

Comment: In fact, it works in 2 dimensions too. This matrix, for example, rotates the plane, while also stretching it by a factor of $2$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}2\cos \theta & -2\sin \theta \\ 2\sin \theta & 2\cos \theta \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest decomposition I see to your issue is the so-called [$QR$ decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition).

It must be said at first that we have to adopt a multiplicative convention for the composition of two operations : we have to write is $RS$ instead of $R+S$ .

The $QR$ decomposition of $A$ is the fact to write $A= QR$ with unique (up to a simultaneous change of sign in $Q$ and $R$) factors $Q$ (your $R$) and $R$ (your $S$) where:

- $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix (not necessarily a rotation matrix),
- $R$ is an upper triangular matrix (which is what you call a "stretch matrix").

Comment: You're right, it should probably be a multiplication, not an addition!

Comment: In fact, the stretching you are referring too would be a homothety, whereas, a triangular matrix accounts geometrically for what is called a **shear** operation (also called a transvection).

Comment: I see, I haven't accounted for the shear operation. So the QR-decomposition is probably the closest thing to what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. There is another decomposition named the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) where the second factor, instead of being a triangular matrix is a positive definite matrix, which is quite different from a stretching...

Answer (score 0):

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$ is a linear transformation that is neither a rotation, nor a *stretching* (according to your definition which is strange), nor either a mirroring.

Comment: Is it perhaps a combination of them?

Comment: It clearly is a combination of a rotation and a stretching. It rotates in the plane of the first 2 components, and stretches by a factor of $2$ in the subspace of the 3rd and 4th components.